# Why doesn't Ruby RSS retrieve the entire feed from Wordpress RSS?

Tags: ruby, rss

I wrote a quick bit in Ruby to consume an RSS feed from Wordpress. A dumbed down version looks like this:

```
require 'rss'
@rss = RSS::Parser.parse(open('http://blog.allbouttexas.com/feed/').read, false).items[0..3]
@rss.each do |rss|
  puts rss.dc_creator
end
```

This works great, then, when I deployed to my production server and executed it, I got:

```
undefined method 'dc_creator'
```

I am a little boggled by this and did some debugging. It appears that when the RSS feed is retrieved on the production server, not ALL elements are included in the `@rss` object. Another element not included is `content_encoded`.

I then changed my local copy by modifying the include to this:

```
require 'rss/2.0.
```

After doing this, I get the same error as on production. Appears that my versions of RSS are different.

Also, after research, it appears that the RSS libraries do not have access to Dublin Core elements. Trying to figure out how to access these elements via RSS.

Comment: In my experience, the RSS module is getting a bit old. I wrote my own aggregator for RDF, RSS and Atom using Net::HTTP and Nokogiri, but I'd recommend looking at [Feedzirra](https://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra).

Comment: Just went ahead and re-wrote in Nokogiri. Doesn't seem to be as quick as the RSS option, but will work.

Comment: It should be a lot faster. You might be doing things in Ruby that could better be done in libXML2 via XPaths.